# Crontab for script

Tags: linux, shell, cron

My script is under /u01/software/aditya/script/ directory. Name of script is myscript.sh. I am able to run this script and getting output too. I am trying to set a cronjob for this script at 6.30 daily morning. I am doing this as root user. I have done following steps but not getting output.

```
crontab -e
30 06 * * * sh /u01/software/aditya/script/myscript.sh >> /u01/software/aditya/hello.log
:wq
```

but not getting any update in hello.log file :( . please help….

Comment: Is the `:wq` really in your `crontab`? Try removing it...

Comment: I fixed the markdown. :wq is in the editor (vi, I guess).

Comment: I'll bet it's the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453432/hourly-cron-job-did-not-run

Comment: @Adi I deleted my answer because I misunderstood the ":wq" part was illustrating what you are typing to vi, not input meant for vi sneaking into your crontab instead.

Answer (score 1):

First check your cron log file which is usually in `/var/log/syslog`. There should be entries similar to

```
Sep 17 06:30:01 localhost CRON[17725]: (root) CMD (sh /u01/software/aditya/script/myscript.sh >> /u01/software/aditya/hello.log)
```

If not, your script has never been run. This could be due to a broken `crontab` file. You should make sure that this file always ends with a *newline*, better insert more than one at the end so that deleting one accidentally won't break the file.

If this line exists in the log file then your script has been run, but didn't generate any output. This can happen due to a different environment when being run via `cron`.

Also note that `>>` only redirects *stdout*, not *stderr*. If you want to redirect *stderr* too, then add `2>&1` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is caused by a `PATH` problem. There is a very good chance that `myscript.sh` calls a command that is not available in the `PATH` that cron runs with. Some options to fix this are:

- Make sure that every command in `myscript.sh` is a full path-reference (tedious)
- Add `source ~/.bashrc` to the top of `myscript.sh`
- Add `export PATH=$PATH:<colon delimited list of paths necessary for myscript.sh to run correctly>`

Pick one of the above, or you could also choose one of the options here: [Hourly cron job did not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453432/hourly-cron-job-did-not-run)